# WinDbg is unable to communicate with the target after some time

Tags: windows, windbg

Host and target are both Windows 7 x64.
The session goes well, but sometimes after 15-20 minutes the target freezes (like a break point was hit), but WinDbg reports that the debuggee is running and it can not take commands. Also, when I attempt to break into the target (ctrl + break)  I am told that I can't communicate with the target:

> Wrote 0 of 1 bytes of the breakin packet.
>   Failed to write breakin packet to target.  HRESULT 0x80004005
>   WARNING: The HOST cannot communicate with the TARGET!

If I am quick to catch the moment, the first errors are different: Win32 error 0n23 and Win32 error 0n121. I looked around for this error, but I could not find something related to WinDbg.

The only way I can resume my session is to shut down the target by pressing it's power button.

At first I thought this has something to do with the target entering stand by, but I modified the power options so it should never enter in a sleep state and I started to actively use it.

I thought this was my driver's fault (although it just iterates through some LIST_ENTRYs and displays some addresses with DbgPrint) so I restarted the target and never loaded my driver.

I noticed that right before this happens the target display goes black for a moment. Any place where I should start looking?

Comment: Which version of WinDbg (6.2.9200 / 6.3.9600)? This sounds like kernel debugging. IEEE1394 or other setup? Please give more details.

Comment: WinDbg 7600.16385, debugging over 1934. Lately it stopped happening. I tried to pinpoint it to something in my driver, but nothing came out. Maybe it's just a bug and I had the bad luck of experiencing it multiple times in a row.